# Почему список перестает получать элементы после очищения?

Tags: python, list, insert

Программа переводит число 71 в системы счисления от 4 до 100 и должна выводить полученные числа. В итоге программа выводит число только после перевода в систему счисления с основанием 4, а далее выводит пустые строки.

```
x = 71
for s in range(4,101):
    a = []
    while x > 0:
        m = x % s
        a.insert(0, str(m))
        x //= s
    a = ''.join(a)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Потому что вы безвозвратно уничтожаете изначальное число 71, список тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Неправильно переводите. Для систем с основанием больше 10 у вас должно быть соответствующее количество "цифр". А у вас только 10. Очевидно, что 71 в 12-ричной системе не 511.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно `x = 74` включить внутрь цикла for, так как вы первой итерацией for обнуляете x, и соответственно больше не входите в цикл while на следующий итерациях.

```
for s in range(4, 101):
    x = 71
    a = []
    while x > 0:
        m = x % s
        a.insert(0, str(m))
        x //= s
    a = ''.join(a)
    print(a)
```